# How to get list of all items in a dynamo Table using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, key, command-line-interface

I need to get the list of all items under Platform key in a certain Dynamodb Table called JKOwner using AWS CLI. This is what I'm currently trying to test:

```
aws dynamodb get-item --table-name JKOwner --key '{"Platform": {"S": "GOVTEST"}}'
```

Using this cli command, I am able to get the item GOVTEST under the Platform key. But what command should I use if I need to get all items aside from GOVTEST so I could store it in a variable? There are around 200+ Platform values which I need to get into the list. The details of the item doesn't really matter as of now. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

If you truly need to get all items, you should use a Scan operation. Then you use a filter expression to omit items where platform = GOVTEST items.

If you want to make it really easy on yourself, you could use [PartiQL for DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.html) and do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM JKOwner WHERE Platform <> 'GOVTEST'
```

For an example of doing PartiQL on the command line, [look on the PartiQL for DynamoDB tab on this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/getting-started-step-3.html) or do this:

```
aws dynamodb execute-statement --statement "SELECT * FROM Music   \
                                            WHERE Artist='Acme Band' AND SongTitle='Happy Day'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```sh
aws dynamodb query 
  --table-name JKOwner
  --key-condition-expression "Platform = :v1" 
  --expression-attribute-values "{ \":v1\" : { \"S\" : \"GOVTEST\" } }"
```

Comment: sorry, i actually saw this already from other sites I researched with and I don't think this solves my problem. what does this mean? --key-condition-expression "Platform = :v1" i'm not actually familiar with this. Also, I have to get ALL items under the JKOwner table (that's 200+ Items including GOVTEST).

Comment: It means get all rows with a key named `Platform` that's equal to GOVTEST. If the `Platform` column of your table is not part of the key (Partition, Sort Key or any index), you have to use `scan` instead of `query`